# Prestashop custom field in groups in admin

Tags: php, controller, prestashop-1.6

I have edit AdminGroupsController.php and add one field to renderForm function, like :

```
array(
      'type' => 'text',
       'label' => $this->l('Myfield'),
       'name' => 'my_field',
```

and name is same as database column. But I don't get how or where it does the edit and/or add action so I can add the field to be saved to the database. It will post the field now but it does not save it.

Another issue is, I have in override/controllers/admin/AdminGroupsController.php :

```
class AdminGroupsController extends AdminGroupsControllerCore
{
  public function renderForm()
  {
```

but it does not work, even I delete cache_index file from cache.
I had to do the edits to the controllers/admin/AdminGroupsController.php ...

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had to copy classes/Group.php to override/classes/Group.php and modify it:

```
class Group extends GroupCore
{
```

Seems to be the model for this.

and to add fiel(d) to the model I wanted to update, and it seems it will fetch that also when I try to edit the group.

Also, I still don't know why overriding AdminGroupController DOES NOT work, but overriding this class (model) works...

Comment: If you look at AdminGroupController's `__construct()` you will see a line `$this->className = 'Group';`. This tells the admin controller to bind any form or list to object model `Group`. In `renderForm()` you specify which properties or this object (table columns) are to be displayed and be available for editing. So when you save a form it creates object model `Group`, adds properties to it from your form and saves it. If you don't have a overriden model with custom properties, it obviously won't save them to database.